# The derangement problem with everyone having two items

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

The derangement problem is like, "There are n people each having a hat. All the n hats are put in a box. Suppose each person takes one hat randomly from the box. What is the probability that no one gets his/her own hat." Then, what if those n people each have two hats and would take two hats randomly from the box? what is the probability that everyone gets their own two hats from the box?

For example, "In an activity, everyone prepares k hats and puts them into a box. People take hats in turn. In the turn of a person, they take k gifts from the box uniformly at random one by one (without replacement)."

Then, if n = 6 and k = 2, what is the probability that everyone gets the two hats prepared by themself?

Can this problem be solved by:
$\frac{1}{12C2 \times 10C2 \times 8C2 \times 6C2 \times 4C2 \times 2C2}$
(C is for combination)

Also, for the question "what is the probability that everyone gets at least one hat not prepared by themself?", is it just simply 1 - the former probability?

and

When k = 2 and n is unknown. In the turn of person X, if the first hat X takes is from person Y, what is the probability that the other gift X takes is also from Y?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "No one gets their two hats" means no one gets both of their hats, or that no one gets either of their hats?  (Both questions are potentially interesting.)  What would you like to be counting in the case $n = 2$, for example?

Comment: Do you know how the simple derangement problem is solved using inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes

Comment: A natural starting point would be to review the solution(s) for the classical derangement problem and to try to adapt one of those.

Comment: @JBL I changed to e.g. everyone gets their two own hats

Comment: That is a completely different question from either version of the original.

Comment: Note:  the edit completely changes the nature of the problem.  Please edit to include your efforts.  Post edit, a natural step is to solve it by hand for small $n$ and look for patterns.

Comment: You should certainly add to the question the example when $n = 2$.

Comment: @JBL ok let me make an example

Comment: The "everyone gets their own hat(s)" version seems like it'll be generally less interesting than the "no one gets their own hat(s)"; it'll be some version of $1/n!$, possibly with a factor of $2^n$ floating around in there.

Comment: As rephrased now, this is not about derangements or even like derangements. The problem with derangements is that you want the probability that nobody is matching. Making the question about everybody matching makes it easy.

Comment: It is $\frac{2^n}{(2n)!},$ @BrianTung Or, more generally, $\frac{(k!)^n}{(kn)!}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews when k = 2 and n unknown. In the turn of person X, if the first gift X takes is from person Y, what is the probability that the other gift X takes is also from Y?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but easier to write in terms of multinomials. Given $m$ and $a_1,\dots,a_k$ such that $a_1+\dots+a_k=m$ we write: $$\binom{m}{a_1,\dots,a_k}=\frac{m!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_k!}$$ which counts the number of ways to partition $m$ elements into $k$ ordered subsets with the $i$th subset having $a_i$ elements.

Comment: Then your answer for $n=6,k=2$ becomes: $$\frac{1}{\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}}=\frac{2^6}{12!}.$$

Comment: If the first gift that $X$ gets is from $Y,$ the second gift is from $Y$ with probability $\frac{k-1}{kn-1}.$. When $k=2,$ that is $\frac{1}{2n-1}.$ @John

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Isn't this a conditional probability or Bayes Theorem problem? --"Given that the first hat is from person Y, what is the probability that the second is also from person Y?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks, I figured it would be something like that but I was too lazy to think about it. :-P

Comment: @John It's just a simple "There are $2n-1$ gifts we don't know about, and they equally likely to remain undrawn by prior recipients. Of those, there is only one among them that are from $Y,$ so the probability is $\frac{1}{2n-1}.$" It is certainly a conditional logic case, but hardly needs to be though of that way. You can essentially assume that $X$ is the first to draw.